# STT does not work for voice over iPhone recording

Tags: javascript, python, speech-to-text, openai-whisper

After recording on the front end, send it to the server and proceed with STT using whisper. The server saves the voice in .wav format and performs STT through openai's whisper, but only the voice recorded and transmitted from the iPhone is not processed properly (it is not recognized at all).
MacBook, laptop, and desktop microphones are all possible, but only audio recorded from iPhone is not processed (even after installing AirPods or wired earphones).
If I run the separately saved wav file audio in colab, it works normally. Is there any error or something I'm missing?

```
let audioChunks = [];
let mediaRecorder;
let stream;
let audioContext;
let isRecording = false;
let mediaStreamSource;

function toggleRecording() {
    const userMessageInput = document.getElementById('userMessage');
    const recordButton = document.getElementById('record-button');

    if (currentAudio) {
        currentAudio.pause();
        currentAudio = null;
    }

    if (!isRecording) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then(async (userStream) => {
                stream = userStream;
                audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                audioChunks = [];

                if (mediaRecorder) {
                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                        if (event.data.size > 0) {
                            audioChunks.push(event.data);
                            sendIntermediateRecording(event.data);
                        }
                    };
                }

                mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                mediaRecorder.start();
                isRecording = true;
                userMessageInput.disabled = true;
                translateText('Recording Your Voice...')
                    .then(translatedText => {
                        userMessageInput.placeholder = translatedText;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Translation Error:', error);
                    });

                updateButtonState();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                alert('Mic Access Error' , error.message);
                
            });
    } else {
        if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state !== "inactive") {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            isRecording = false;
            updateButtonState();
            recordButton.disabled = isRecording;
        }
    }
}
```

This is run STT code

```
def speech_to_text_whsiper(self, audio_data):

        with open('audio.wav', 'wb') as wav_file:
            wav_file.write(audio_data.read())

        result = self.stt_engine.transcribe('/audio.wav')

        return result['text']
```